# How to set label value on Razor Html.DropDownList

Tags: html, razor

i want to set the label value for a dropdownlist(not the default value, the label value) and i think im doing something wrong

```
@Html.DropDownList("cboCategoria", new SelectList(Model, "ID", "Nome"), new { @id = "cboCategoria", @label = "Categoria-pai: " })
```

Comment: Do you mean the field label, or an internal option label? (Or a label attribute, which doesn't exist)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it a few ways, The label is seperate from the creation of the actual `<select>`:

```
<label>Categoria-pai: @Html.DropDownList(...)</label>
```

OR

```
<label for="cboCategoria">Categoria-pai:</label> @Html.DropDownList(...)
```

OR

```
@* This assumes you are creating the dropdown from a property named 
   cboCategoria in your Model *@
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.cboCategoria) @Html.DropDownList(...)
```

EDIT:  I did want to note, that if you use the last method, you will want a [Display] attribute on your Model's property.

Comment: i thought it had a way to set on the htmlattributes, so i can assume i was wrong?

Comment: You can add any attributes you want with the htmlattributes.  HTML label elements are seperate from the actual input/select elements.  There is no standard in HTML5 for a label attribute.  You could possibly create a custom attribute `data-my-custom-label` and use unobtrusive javascript to create the `<label>`, but there is nothing out of the box.